# Need a MySQL query to delete Wordpress comments

Tags: mysql, wordpress, comments, duplicates, disqus

My wordpress site was recently hacked so I had to reinstall everything. Wordpress resinstalled, database backups imported, everything fine and dandy. Then I installed the Disqus plugin and synced (Disqus was previously used before the site was hacked). Big no-no apparantly. Now I have a duplicate of every single comment on my site! Even worse, the duplicate comments have been synced BACK to Disqus!

So, I know this is a simple query in PHPMyAdmin but I don't know it! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The query for deleting in mysql is

```
Delete from (tablename) where (primarykey)
```

But I think wordpress has its build in database queries for select delete and update.

Here's another if you use the plugin  Disqus

> *If you're logged into your Disqus account you can also choose to delete a comment at your dashboard. This will remove it from your profile and remove all identifying information from the comment on the original page. Once a comment has been anonymized it cannot be claimed again.*

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there is [a WordPress Stack Exchange website](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) ;)

I would use PHP unless you know the wpdb name off the top of your head. Be sure to back up the DB first! Like so:

```
global $wpdb;

$comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments"
   ." ORDER BY comment_post_ID, comment_content");

$prev = NULL;

foreach($comments as $comment) {

  if ($prev && $prev->comment_content == $comment->comment_content
    && $prev->comment_post_ID == $comment->comment_post_ID ) { // add maybe other rules here

    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments" WHERE comment_ID == $comment- >comment_ID");

  }
  else
    $prev = $comment;
}
```

Comment: @digitaltoday Hi, maybe I'm confused, but I tried running this and I got an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/electroj/public_html/comment.php on line 8`

Answer (score 0):

If he doesn't know how use mysql, I think re editing the wp interface is great, because usually wp creating there build function for queries. And it may lead again to destruction of it.

The only reason why it doesn't work maybe its because of the plug in they use.! I think so.!